# What is it called when you tell the truth in a misleading 'nice' way?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Basically when you try to put makeup on the truth, for example when instead of calling someone autistic they call them special?

Comment: It's "soft-peddling".

Comment: A *euphemism*, you mean?

Comment: There are lots of posts including 'soft-peddle' and 'euphemism'. They bracket this, so I'll choose one as a duplicate.

Comment: It's not 'soft-peddling'. It's soft-**pedalling** (or '-pedaling' in the US, I expect). A metaphorical usage,  derived from the soft (or 'una corda') pedal on a piano, meaning 'toning down, damping, muting or obscuring'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I'd always been given the impression that it was referring to a peddler -- a salesman -- and that it was a synonym for "soft-sell" (another possible term for the original question).  And some sources back this up.  But I see that many references relate it to the piano pedal, as you suggest.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is **pedal**